# I can't get all the elements to stay on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get the "about me" "contact" and "portfolio" all on to stay on the same line as the my name section, even though they are on the same div. And I can't use positioning because this bootstrap.

How can I solve this?

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid border" style="overflow:visible">
  <a href="#" class="nameBlock"> Vamsi Krishna Pappusetti</a>
  <ul class="nav row justify-content-end" id="navbar">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Remove class `row` from <ul> element

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea:

I made the container `<div>` into a `nav row`, with `p-0` and `m-0` to clear padding and margins.
I made the "name" link into a `nav-link` so it's padding is the same as other links.
I set `ml-auto` on the `<ul>` to align it to the right side.

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="nav row border container-fluid p-0 m-0">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">Vamsi Krishna Pappusetti</a>
  <ul class="nav ml-auto">
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine "nameBlock" and "navbar" into a `row` div and use `ml-auto` (Margin utilities) in Bootstrap 4 to align navbar to end.

Code: https://codepen.io/1412108/pen/BVLRRP

[Bootstrap 4 Margin Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#margin-utilities)